# An Explicit Isomorphism Between the Three Dimensional Orthogonal Lie Algebra and the Special Linear Lie Algebra of Dimension $3$

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I know from various sources (http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdf/research/y4_fowlerwright.pdf and 
https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Other/Samelson-LieAlg.pdf are two) that the complex orthogonal Lie algebra of dimension 3, $\mathfrak{o}_3(\mathbb C)$, (by which I mean the space of skew-symmetric matrices of size 3) is isomporphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$, but I cannot come up with an explicit isomorphism. Can someone give me one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an explicit isomorphism of Lie algebras
$$
\mathfrak{o}_3(\Bbb C)= \mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb C)\cong \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)
$$
see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3866709/what-is-a-direct-proof-of-the-isomorphism-mathfrakso3-mathbb-c-simeq-ma?noredirect=1&lq=1). One can find many more posts here on this site:

[Is there an intelligent way to find the Lie algebra isomorphism $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})\simeq\mathfrak{o}_3(\mathbb{C})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276380/the-lie-algebras-mathfrako-3-mathbbc-and-mathfraksl-2-mathbbc?rq=1)

[Lie algebra isomorphism between $\mathfrak{sl}(2,{\bf C})$ and $\mathfrak{so}(3,\Bbb C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423419/lie-algebra-isomorphism-between-rm-sl2-bf-c-and-bf-so3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: First link is dead.

Comment: @Bcpicao I have replaced the link.